# error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall rectangle::rectangle(void)" (??0rectangle@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _main

Tags: c++

The following code is part of a tutorial.  I have checked the code against the tutorial umpteen times, and although it works on the video, my program has the following error:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: simpleclass, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall rectangle::rectangle(void)" (??0rectangle@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _main
1>C:\Users\Bob K\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\simpleclass\Debug\simpleclass.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

This is the code:

```
#include <iostream>

class rectangle
{
private:
    double length;
    double width;
public:
    rectangle();
    ~rectangle();
        double calcperim() const;
        double calcarea() const;
        double getlength() const;
        double getwidth() const;
        void setlength(double l);
        void setwidth(double w);

};

rectangle::~rectangle()
{
}

double rectangle::calcperim() const
{
    return ( length + length + width + width);
}

double rectangle::getlength() const
{
    return length;
}

double rectangle::getwidth()const
{
    return width;
}

void rectangle::setwidth( double w)
{   
    width = w;
}
void rectangle::setlength(double l)
{
    length = l;
}

double rectangle::calcarea() const
{
    return (length * width);
}



int main()
{
using namespace std;

    rectangle r;
    r.setwidth(3);
    r.setlength(9);

    cout << "length " << r.getlength() << endl;
    cout << "width " << r.getwidth() << endl;
    cout << "perimiter: " << r.calcperim() << endl;
    cout << "Area: " << r.calcarea() << endl;


    system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Please help.  I used to program years ago and I'm trying to get back to doing it.

Answer (score 6):

You're missing an implementation of the `rectangle` constructor

```
rectangle::rectangle()
{
    length = 0;
    width = 0;
}
```

Alternatively, if you don't care about initialising the members, just remove the definition of the constructor from the class definition.  (Note that this probably isn't advisable; I'm just including it for completeness.)

Comment: Those two lines are **assignments**, not initialization. Initialization is done in the aptly named initializer list, not in the body of the constructor: `rectangle::rectangle : length(0), width(0) { }` If you don't initialize members they'll get initialized anyway; for integer members it doesn't matter much, but if initialization and assignment are expensive, it's better to initialize rather than initialize then assign.

Comment: @PeteBecker I avoided using an initialiser list here as it wasn't vital to the answer and seemed to add extra complexity for a beginner. Point taken about the sloppy terminology though.  I'm interested in your comment about built in types being initialised automatically.  I didn't think members of built in types were set to any predictable value by default (debuggers and valgrind seem to agree).  Are you saying otherwise or are built in types considered to have constructors which don't set their value?